# Report MemoryError and OverflowError arbitrarily

Tags: python, python-3.x, allocation

I employed the "Sieve of Eratosthenes" to produce primes.

```
def primes(n):
    if n < 2:
        return None
    primes_sieve = [True] * (n + 1) 
    primes_sieve[1] = False
    primes_sieve[0] = False

    # sieve
    for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):  
        if primes_sieve[i]:
            for j in range(i * i, n + 1, i):  
                primes_sieve[j] = False

    return [i for i, p in enumerate(primes_sieve) if p]
```

It works well for small numbers.

```
In [28]: primes(2**10)[:10]              
Out[28]: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
In [29]: primes(2**10)[-10:]             
Out[29]: [967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, 1019, 1021]
In [30]: primes(2**15)[-10:]             
Out[30]: [32633, 32647, 32653, 32687, 32693, 32707, 32713, 32717, 32719, 32749]
```

For some big numbers, it report errors arbitrarily.

Memory Error

```
In [32]: primes(2**30)[-10:]             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-3e546166a3d9> in <module>
----> 1 primes(2**30)[-10:]

<ipython-input-26-5f07bf9cb49e> in primes(n)
      2     if n < 2:
      3         return None
----> 4     primes_sieve = [True] * (n + 1)
      5     primes_sieve[1] = False
      6     primes_sieve[0] = False

MemoryError:
```

and  OverflowError:

```
In [35]: primes(2**100)[-10:]            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-3bb8857d5f28> in <module>
----> 1 primes(2**100)[-10:]

<ipython-input-26-5f07bf9cb49e> in primes(n)
      2     if n < 2:
      3         return None
----> 4     primes_sieve = [True] * (n + 1)
      5     primes_sieve[1] = False
      6     primes_sieve[0] = False

OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer
```

What's the problem? I am delighted and curious to find that python has OverflowError as well.

Answer (score 1):

Python `list`s are implemented as dynamically sized C arrays of pointers to Python objects. When you do:

```
primes_sieve = [True] * (n + 1)
```

where `n` is `2**30`, you're asking for a single contiguous memory allocation of `2**32` (on a 32 bit system) or `2**33` (on a 64 bit system) bytes. On a 32 bit build of Python, the former is impossible; the entire virtual memory address space, user + kernel, is `2**32` bytes, some of which is unusable, some of which is already in use. Python immediately rejects a request for more memory than there is address space. Even on a 64 bit system, the system may reject a request for that much memory (e.g. if it lacks sufficient space in the pagefile/swapfile to handle that memory) for whatever reason, and Python will report it the same way, as a `MemoryError`.

The `OverflowError` is just telling you that the value you passed couldn't fit in the underlying C type involved. `list` (on CPython) stores its size as a `signed size_t` (`Py_ssize_t` is the `typedef`) which is limited to either `2**31 - 1` or `2**63 - 1`; either way, much smaller than `2 ** 100 + 1`. Before CPython even tries to perform the allocation, it's trying to extract the requested size as a `signed size_t`, and dying immediately when it's unable to do so.

Point is, trying to make `list`s of size `2**30` is *almost* always wrong, and making one of size `2**100` (which can't fit on any system in the world) is doomed from the get-go. You can't make the Sieve of Eratosthenes perform a complete sieve to `2**100` in Python, or in any other language; at best you could sieve bits and pieces up to around `2**64` (by sieving up the square root of the top of the range, then using those numbers to sieve a small subset of numbers, like the top 10 you seemed to be testing, but not the whole range).

Side-note: If you're implementing a Sieve of Eratosthenes, a first step to reducing memory consumption would be to replace:

```
primes_sieve = [True] * (n + 1)
```

with:

```
primes_sieve = bytearray('\x01') * (n + 1)
```

That'll reduce the cost-per-item in the sieve from a pointer to a single byte, reducing your memory usage by a factor of 4-8x. You can further halve memory requirements by only storing information on odd numbers (since aside from `2`, which you can hard-code, only odd numbers can be prime). From there, you could move to using third-party classes that can provide a packed bitset (reducing memory usage by another factor of 8x, from a byte to a bit). There are further optimizations available, but most of them will be quite slow in Python (you'd have to move to C to see the benefit); that can be research for you.